# Setting "-D" variables inside CMake

Tags: cmake, vcpkg

I am using vcpkg and I would like to set the variable **VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET** to my specific triplet.

The help here https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/integration/#using-an-environment-variable-instead-of-a-command-line-option (bottom of the page) says you need to pass it as a -D option to CMake, but I would like to set it in my CMakeLists.txt.

I have tried the following two options, but both do not seem to work:

```
set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET "x64-mingw-static" CACHE STRING "") # doesn't work
set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET "x64-mingw-static") # also doesn't work
```

The reason I want to do this in CMakeLists.txt and not the command line is because of my current setup with VS Code and the CMakeTools extension.

How can I "simulate" the -D flag inside my CMakeLists?

I should also mention that my whole "project" consists of a top-level CMakeLists as a sort of "master project" which then includes a sub-folder with another CMakeLists and my "actual" project (the one with the find_package commands).

Comment: You can pass `-D` arguments to the CMake command line via Visual Studio Code. Just open **Settings**, search for "*cmake configure args*" in the settings search bar, and under **CMake: Configure Args** click **Add Item** to append arguments to be passed to `cmake`. Not sure if you want to do this though...

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. What I need is the ability to set the triplet based on all the different kits I have setup. CMake Tools doesn't allow you to pas -D arguments from the kits directly, but does allow you to set CMake environment variables per kit. So I need to use those environment variables to "pass" a -D option.Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Make sure your settings comes **before** the very first `project()` call, when vcpkg toolchain is actually executed.

Comment: @Tsyvarev they are before

Answer (score 2):

Try with `add_compile_definitions` or `target_compile_definitions`

Like this

```
add_compile_definitions(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET="x64-mingw-static")
```

or

```
target_compile_definitions(targetname PUBLIC VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET="x64-mingw-static")
```

[CMake Tutorial](http://goorep.se:1001/changelog/report/rSelect/PAGE_result.htm?alias=guest&set=api&query=Book%20pages&$$TArticleBook1.ArticleBookK=7107&link=%5B%5B%229F1E006D78894848838A0970E2FF0BE9zoom%22,%22Object1%22,7107%5D%5D&rows=25)