# Set "VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET" variable inside CMakeLists.txt

Tags: vcpkg

I need to be able set VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET inside my CMakeLists.txt due to my setup (see my post here: [Setting "-D" variables inside CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63268761/setting-d-variables-inside-cmake?noredirect=1#comment111879954_63268761)) but I cannot get it working.

It works if I pass "x64-mingw-static" as a -D argument, but not if I set it manually. The packages are simply not found in this case.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Try `set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET <yourvalue> CACHE STRING "")`

the behavior you observed was probably fixed by
https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pull/13713

and you used `set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET <yourvalue>)`

Be aware that changing the triplet in an already present cmake cache requires a complete clean reconfigure due to way cmake works.

Comment: Note: This must be used before `project(...`

Comment: @AntonioCS, Can you explain why we should add it before project?

Comment: Because the toolchain gets loaded with `project()`. If the variable is not set until then it won't be used.